# Python Errors when importing module from child directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project that has this file structure:

```
f1
  f2
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
  main.py
```

main.py

```
from f2 import a
...
```

a.py

```
import b
...
```

b.py

```
print('Hello World!')
...
```

When I run main.py, I get an import error from a.py saying "ImportError: No module named 'b'" but when I run a.py, it functions as expected.

f2 was initially a github submodule and the repo name had dashes. I thought that might have been the problem so I changed f2 to a directory and copied over the files. This has not solved my issue.

I have also tried using importlib.

I would expect that a.py is able to import b.py since it is able to when I run a.py directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `a` thinks that `b` is a standalone module, so it looks for it in the `PYTHONPATH` directories, including the current folder.

However, when you run from `main`, `b` is no longer in the current folder (`main`'s folder), and so `a` can't find it.

To solve this, change the import in `a.py` to `from . import b`, which signals that `b.py` is in the *same* package and to perform a relative import accordingly.